# Where are the sample projects in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, project

In older versions of Xcode they have been in the developer folder, just wondering where they are available now, do I have to download them from somewhere?

Comment: ha, so there isn't a big collection of them provided by apple somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find the name of the project you want from the Documentation tab in Organiser you can simple choose "Open Project" and it will be downloaded to a folder of your choice.

Make sure you have downloaded the documentation first via xCode/Preferences/Downloads/Documentation/Check & Install Now.

Comment: ahh, yes I see now, they are all mixed in with the documentation, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

There a lot of sample codes. Just a simple search in google.

Here:

1. [raywenderlich iPhone Tutorials with source code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)
2. [Github - search for repos](https://github.com/)
3. [Apple's own sample codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Types)
4. [The Open Source iPhone Apps List in maniac dev](http://maniacdev.com/2010/06/35-open-source-iphone-app-store-apps-updated-with-10-new-apps/)
5. [Cocos2d samples](http://maniacdev.com/2011/12/over-90-ios-source-code-examples-many-using-cocos2d/)
6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353130/where-can-i-find-sample-iphone-code

I bet this is a good start.
Hope this helps. Have fun.